# Google NodeJS Gmail API fetching next / previous thread for single thread pagination

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-nodejs-client

With https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client I can fetch an email thread and display its all messages properly after decoding body data as like https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get#request

But after displaying one email thread I have a pagination of next/prev email thread.

How can I call api to fetch previous / next email thread ? Can anyone guide me a bit on this? You know, on that single thread details page I have threadID but nothing for next thread / previous thread like pageToken.

Thanks in advance
Jewel Ahmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would list a page at a time, but if you absolutely have to have a token for the next message, you could just [list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#try-it) one message at a time and use the `nextPageToken` for the next message.

You will have to do two requests for every message though: list and [get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) the message.

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?maxResults=1&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "154995c3613cd8f9",      // Get this message
   "threadId": "154995c3613cd8f9"
  }
 ],
 "nextPageToken": "07610562483470863557", // Use this next time
 "resultSizeEstimate": 1
}
```

Comment: This solution actually is not possible to use here in my case because, to view a message/thread I need to use it's unique ID as I am on message/thread details UI, so if I use any unique id then in that case next page token is not possible!

Another example is: lets say I am viewing 120th [using unique thread/message ID] number of message/thread from INBOX mailbox, then how can I find 121th / 119th number  message/thread?